# How to append values to a list in Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
def get_probe_pts(surf_data, probe_loc):
    rescale_x = surf_data[:, 0] - np.min(surf_data[:, 0])
    # surf_data = data
    surf_data[:, 0] = rescale_x / (5 * 101.6)

    prom_loc_min = probe_loc - (surf_data[1, 0] - surf_data[0, 0]) * 0.5
    prom_loc_max = probe_loc + (surf_data[1, 0] - surf_data[0, 0]) * 0.5

    data_probe = surf_data[np.logical_and(surf_data[:, 0] > prom_loc_min, surf_data[:, 0] < prom_loc_max)]

    return np.average(data_probe, axis=0)
```

```
probes = {'k20': 0.05, 'k21': 0.15, 'k22': 0.25, 'k23': 0.35, 'k24': 0.45, 'k25': 0.55, 'k26': 0.65, 'k27': 0.75,
          'k28': 0.85, 'k29': 0.95}

for i in range(str_idx, end_idx):
    data = np.loadtxt('./cavity_flr' + str(i) + '.csv', usecols=(0, 1, 3, 7))
    for key in probes:
        probe_data.setdefault(key, []).append(get_probe_pts(data, probes[key]))
```

Only for the k20 key, values are appended properly. For the rest of the keys, I get nan. But if I loop for each key separately as shown below, it works fine.

```
 for i in range(str_idx, end_idx):
     data = np.loadtxt('./cavity_flr' + str(i) + '.csv', usecols=(0, 1, 3, 7))
     probe_data['k20'].append(get_probe_pts(data, probes['k20']))

 for i in range(str_idx, end_idx):
     data = np.loadtxt('./cavity_flr' + str(i) + '.csv', usecols=(0, 1, 3, 7))
     probe_data['k21'].append(get_probe_pts(data, probes['k21']))
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: ```{'k20': array([[0.0492126 , 0.986368  , 0.751577  ],
        [0.0492126 , 0.98566283, 0.75178633],
        [0.0492126 , 0.9851355 , 0.75198333]]),
 'k21': [array([nan, nan, nan]),
  array([nan, nan, nan]),
  array([nan, nan, nan])],
 'k22': [array([nan, nan, nan]),
  array([nan, nan, nan]),
  array([nan, nan, nan])],
 'k23': [array([nan, nan, nan]),
  array([nan, nan, nan]),
  array([nan, nan, nan])],...```

Something like this. For the first key I get right values, for the rest, i get nan :(

Comment: why are you appending to the return value of `setdefault`?  whilst that works with a muteable, it's just confusing (IMHO)---and it won't work at all with a non muteable

Comment: From ```get_probe_pts(data, probes[key])``` function i get NumPy array as output. I need to append this array to  to list

Comment: If the values in `probe_data` are supposed to be arrays, why are you using a list in `setdefault()`?

Comment: `get_probe_data` modifies `data` in place, so calling it twice produces different results.

Comment: Either the function should make a copy instead of modifying it, or you should make a copy before calling it.

Comment: Thanks. ```np.copy(surf_data)``` helped.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the "update" method instead.
Example: append a key="k50" and value = 0.65
We do : probes.update("k50" : 0.65)

Comment: That's not valid syntax, you're missing `{}`.

Comment: And there's no difference between that and `probes["k50"] = 0.65`